# Locking mutex before using std::condition_variable

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I have a question related to `std::condition_variable`. I read a lot about it and all examples shown locked mutex before using `std::condition_variable` like that:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
condition_variable.wait(lock);
//...
```

or like that:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
condition_variable.notify_one();
//...
```

Is it necessery to lock mutex before using condition variable or is it thread-safe?

Comment: `wait` requires as an argument an `std::unique_lock` instance that represents a locked mutex. `notify_one` doesn't have to be called under a mutex

Comment: What about std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mutex, std::defer_lock) then?

Comment: Which part of "represents a locked mutex" do you find unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `notify_one()` doesn't need a locked mutex in order to be called, but `wait(lock)` does. `condition_variable` is somewhat unfortunately named because it gives the option to wait **unconditionally** for something to happen. A more useful version is [wait(lock, condition)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait), where the thread waits *only if* the condition is *not* true, otherwise it doesn't wait at all.

An analogy can be made with a hotel reception desk, where the `condition_variable` in a worker thread is a receptionist, the mutex represents a critical shared resource (say, a computer for making reservations), and the condition is the **presence of patrons**. Checking into a hotel involves a lot of steps, most of which can be done in parallel by different receptionists, but that one step of entering your details into the computer can't - receptionists have to use the computer one at a time.

Assume that the first thing that receptionists do when they get to work is check if the computer is free (no other receptionists are using it). In the case of `wait(lock)`, receptionists will do that and then **immediately fall asleep** regardless of whether there are people waiting at the reception to be checked in. In the case of `wait(lock, condition)` they will fall asleep *only if* the condition is *not true* (there are no people waiting).

Now, if a receptionist is asleep, they are not going to notice when there are people at the desk waiting to be checked in. That's what `notify_one()` does - wakes up a receptionist. The action of waking up a receptionist **does not depend on the state of the computer** (the mutex) - you can keep ringing the bell at the reception desk even if all the receptionists are awake and checking people in like crazy (think a 4-year-old left without supervision who finds the bell...). `notify_one()` wakes up one receptionist, whereas `notify_all()` wakes up *all of them*.

The analogy is not perfect, but it illustrates the dependence between a `condition_variable` and a locked mutex.